# Storing massive temporary files

Tags: php, file, file-upload, storage

This is a practical question, I am working with quite large website which is going to have a big traffic, and this website is based on music. I guess you could say it's somewhat similar to soundcloud.

So i was wondering how should i store files when they are in uploading process, i'm uploading each file via ajax in chunks, so say user uploaded that file half way trough, and just turned his browser off or whatever, this means that file stays there broken and useless...

So i think best way would be to store it in a folder called `temp` and only once it's 100% complete move it to the user folder.

So i guess the question would be something like, is there a better way and if this moving from one folder to the other would cause to much time? Because i imagine there would files between `1mb to 1gb` size so moving `1gb` file would take quite some time...

Comment: php uploads are buffered in memory until the full file is received, and then they're written out to disk. if this is for a busy site, you'll want to use some OTHER mechanism than php to accept the uploads. if the target folder is on the same filesystem (note: filesystem, not drive), then a move operation is very cheap. moving between file systems is a copy/delete operation, which is expensive.

Comment: can the users upload 1gb files on your server?

Comment: on most file systems changing a file name or directory moves no actual data.

Comment: large website with big traffic should be able to afford paid consultant to help you do things right.

Comment: @MarcB the way my script works now, it is receiving data in chunks and appending that data with `file_put_contents` so from what i have tested by killing my browser that file stays there

Comment: in that case you'd want a time job (e.g. cron) that'll go and prune any dead junk in the upload temp folder.

Comment: ITT Megaupload reborn :)